# why is std::copy faster than std::string constructor?

Tags: c++, performance, std, stdstring

I tried these codes, to compare `std::copy` and `std::string`'s constructor.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void construct_test() {
  std::vector<uint8_t> raw_data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1024; i++) {
    raw_data.push_back(i % 256);
  }

  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::string target_data;
  target_data = std::string(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end());
  auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "construct: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish -
                                                                     start)
                   .count()
            << "us" << std::endl;
}

void copy_test() {
  std::vector<uint8_t> raw_data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1024; i++) {
    raw_data.push_back(i % 256);
  }

  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::string target_data;
  target_data.resize(raw_data.size());
  std::copy(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end(), target_data.begin());
  auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "copy: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish -
                                                                     start)
                   .count()
            << "us" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  construct_test();
  copy_test();

  return 0;
}
```

And I got result:

```
construct: 6245us
copy: 1087us
```

`std::copy` is 6x faster!

Is that meeting expectation? If so, what's the reason?
I searched a lot of methods of converting vector to string, but no one mentioned the `std::copy` way. Should I use this way? Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: Writing good performance test is hard. The main pitfall is [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). This rule makes code faster, but testing of small tight code performance becomes hard since now you have to fight with optimizer and make sure that optimized didn't remove code under test. So without reading your code I'm pretty sure this is mian problem.

Comment: how did you compile? And note that `high_resolution_clock` should not be used for benchmarking. Use `steady_clock`

Comment: You are measuring 1 time only and one test case will include overhead from calling `new` for the first time. Not to mention potential optimisations, I'd expect compiler to remove in your measuments entirely.

Comment: you are not using `target_data` to produce any observable effect in both cases. It is to be expected that the calls are optimized away when optimizations are turned on

Comment: Change the order of `construct_test()` and `copy_test()`. Now copy is slower. https://ideone.com/aemRow

Comment: To get reasonable results you should run each test some hundred times and discard the first few results and any outliers. Whichever you run first will be slowest due to cache and cpu warmup. Then you get some outliers when some background process occupies cpu or what not. Running for a few hundred times shows a difference of about 50us: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7c50fdd8788d07d (with the wrong clock still!)

Comment: Doing meaningful and good performance tests is even harder than learning to use a language correctly. Libraries, compiler optimizations, and CPU runtime optimizations are targeting actual use cases. Most tests that one is writing are the opposite. If something like ` std::string(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end())` is really a bottleneck in a real application you can test if `std::copy` is faster.

Comment: Thanks for comments above! I just tried to change the order of calling `construct_test()` and `copy_test()` and got the same result. but @VLL showed me another result. It's really complicated about compiler, compiling params.  And the **as-if rule** is what I just learned today.

Comment: fwiw, there is https://quick-bench.com/, but even that requires some experience to be used correctly, it might still produce misleading results otherwise

Comment: After writing proper test, can't reproduce on [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/S-mEQ_J67aUadocWwoDpfK9Msds) or [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/3nW9YkFn_8iYM-f73wS08sUpro4) BTW I'm surprised how [reserve + copy is slow](https://quick-bench.com/q/uULSLcpYmmKPKNe9w6g-EjrUUpo).

Comment: imho the lesson to learn is that microbenchmarks are extremely hard to do right and it is simpler to profile a real use case. Concerning your question, I am not aware of any reason why one should be significantly faster than the other. Both copy every character to the string.

Comment: @Jason.Pu Any question that concerns the speed of C++ **must** be accompanied by the compiler options you are using to build the program.  If you are timing an unoptimized build or a "debug" build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.  There have been many "speed" related questions here on SO where the poster closed the question, all because they did *not* build their program with optimizations turned on, and found out that the issue was the way they built their program, and nothing to do with the program itself.

Comment: @MarekR The reserve + copy does not surprise me too much. At least for trivial copyable datatypes. Because there, the resize and copy does one resize, and then can do a plain copy into the memory area. `reserve + copy` uses a back inserter, so for every item inserted it has to be checked if the size and capacity are sufficient and the increment of the size for each item. I would suspect that the differences are not that extreme if the compiler can't perform a trivial copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, your testing methodology is deeply flawed. In general, you have to run operations many times (possibly millions or billions) to get meaningful results. Otherwise, the order in which you run the benchmarks, and scheduling etc. may give you drastically different outcomes.

- @463035818_is_not_an_ai has pointed out that you should use `steady_clock` over `high_resolution_clock` for benchmarks (although this is unlikely to have major impact in this case)
- @VLL has pointed out that simply changing the order of `construct_test()` and `copy_test()` makes [one function run faster than the other](https://ideone.com/aemRow).

You can use [google/benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) (used by [QuickBench](https://quick-bench.com/)) to get more meaningful results.

Besides the two methods you have used, there are at least two more ways to create/overwrite strings:

```cpp
// BenchmarkInit
std::string target_data = std::string(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end());

// BenchmarkAssignmentOp
std::string target_data;
target_data = std::string(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end());

// BenchmarkAssign
std::string target_data;
target_data.assign(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end());

// BenchmarkCopy
std::string target_data;
target_data.resize(raw_data.size());
std::copy(raw_data.begin(), raw_data.end(), target_data.begin());
```

We get the following [benchmark results](https://quick-bench.com/q/4U13JJtMQi2I4h9Id5qdOvAGu3M) for clang 15, libstdc++, -O3:
[image]

- Using the `std::string` constructor is best, whether there's an unnecessary default initialization first, or not. The first two methods use `std::memcpy` internally, which should be the fastest way to copy memory.
- `std::copy` is slower, likely because `.resize()` requires zeroing memory first, and isn't getting optimized nicely to `memcpy` , but to vectorized memory operations.
- `.assign` is dramatically slower, likely because there is less partial loop unrolling compared to `std::copy`, so there is a lot of overhead besides just copying memory.

Even with proper benchmarking, you can see unexpected and dramatic differences, and you can only make sense of things when looking at assembly.

#### Update

[I've opened a bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110945#c15) and this performance issue has been patched by [@JonathanWakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely).

Comment: you could try `reserve` instead of `resize` and a `back_inserter` for the `copy` call. Would be interesting to see if that would make it come to the same level as the constructor and assignment

Comment: First, I reviewed my test env, I used Code Runner extension in VS Code to make the test, and its command line is just `g++ $filename` without any compilation options. And I don't know which version it used. Then I tried commenters' compile options, the result was that `std::copy` is similar to `std::string()`. 

And now I understand, maybe even I use the same compiler, same options, same computer, it would still perform differently. There is a long way I need to explore.

Comment: @Jason.Pu -- `g++ $filename` -- It makes no sense to time an unoptimized build.  From the very start, your timings were meaningless because of how you built the program.